# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)

Tags: java, android, c

I am new to android development. I am getting following error in native code (c):

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)

What does it mean....?

Comment: [This might help you a little](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023291/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000000-code-1-phonegap).

Comment: Actually there seem to be quite a few answers in SO - give it a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sigsegv) and see if they help.

Comment: check logcat for stack trace of native code which caused segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

It's a segmentation fault in your native code.