# How To Play MediaPlayer's Next Song without reaching the End of the Current song

Tags: java, android, android-music-player

i have a music player app and it cuts which part of a track should be played.
my question is how do i play the next song even if the current mediaplayer track hasn't reached the end of song. I also tried calling the onCompletion :

```
mplayer.stop();

        Log.v("PLAYER", "Audio track Stopped");
        checkTrackStatus();
        songHandler.removeCallbacks(uxUpdater);
        if(fis!=null)fis=null;

        if((currentTrack+1) < songs.size())
        {

            Log.v("Move to next track", songs.get(currentTrack+1).get("songTitle"));
            //mplayer.release();
            mplayer=null;
            currentTrack++;
            playSong(currentTrack);

        }else
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "All tracks played", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

PLAY SONG METHOD:

```
public void playSong(final int songIndex)
{
        File toPlay = new File(songs.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));

        lblTrackText.setText("Playing ["+(songIndex+1)+"/"+songs.size()+"]");
        lblTrackTitle.setText(songs.get(songIndex).get("songTitle"));
        //lblTrackTitle.setSelected(true);


        Log.v("PLAY SONG : ", toPlay.getPath());
        if(toPlay.exists())
        {
            //playAudio(toPlay);

            try{

                mplayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
                //mplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                fis=new FileInputStream(new File(songs.get(songIndex).get("songPath"))); //ORIGINAL 'p'
                mplayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());//need to add permission in manifest to play .m4a files "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

                mplayer.prepare();




                //final String s =p;
                mplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    //getTotalTrackDuration

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mplayer.seekTo(Integer.parseInt(songs.get(songIndex).get("songStart")));
                        mplayer.start();
                        //lblTotal.setText(timeConverter(mplayer.getDuration()));
                        setTrackNo();

                        //Log.v("NOW PLAYING ", s);
                        updateProgress();
                    }
                });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("AUDIO PLAYER", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), songs.get(songIndex).get("songTitle")+" does not exist or is already deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

i always get an error saying

Error(1,-541478725)
Fatal Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00002ad8 (code=1)

i'm using vitamio media player by the way.

Any help would be great..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get indicates that there is a bug in native code, which must lie in the vitamino media player. The error you are receiving seems to be a memory bug, which makes me think that resources are not freed and the device runs out of memory.

Try adding a call:

```
fis.close()
```

before your code:

```
if(fis!=null)fis=null;
```

to make sure that you are closing your stream to the previous song properly.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14336932/1137118) your problem could also be that you are `loading a lot of images and sounds and causing the app to run out of memory`. It also seems that different devices with different versions of android can handle this differently, meaning that the app could work on one phone but not another.

Comment: Nice! Just out of curiosity, what did you have to change? :)

Comment: thanks man.. i have come up with a solution...
when a specified end time (w/c is not the track's end time) is reached, i called [MediaPlayerObj].seekTo([MediaPlayerObj].getDuration())
in order to invoke onCompletion method...hehe

Comment: @MetaSnarf: Very nice!