# java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 10 (?), fault addr 006e006f

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have built an apk in Unity3d 4.6 with no errors. But I am constantly receiving Crashing Reports mostly from Samsung Devices.
Here is one of the crash report:

```js
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain]
Unity version     : 4.6.1f1
Device model      : samsung SM-E700F
Device fingerprint: samsung/e7ltexx/e7lte:5.1.1/LMY47X/E700FXXU1BOL3:user/release-keys

Caused by: java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 10 (?), fault addr 006e006f
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/e7ltexx/e7lte:5.1.1/LMY47X/E700FXXU1BOL3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '7'
pid: 2135, tid: 2135, name: ion.city.battle  >>> com.offshore.commando.action.city.battle <<<
    r0 b9650014  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    r4 b9650014  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
    r8 b96de680  r9 00000000  sl b96f8450  fp 00000000
    ip b8f3f3b8  sp 00000000  lr 00002878  pc b9806b80  cpsr 46303037

 at [heap].00bd2b80(Native Method)
 at Unknown.00002874(Unknown Source)
 at MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(Native Method)
 at MonoMethod.Invoke(<0x00184>:388)
 at MethodBase.Invoke(<0x0004b>:75)
 at AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke(<0x00167>:359)
 at AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke(<0x00093>:147)
 at _AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod(<0x000ff>:255)
 at <Module>.runtime_invoke_intptr_object_intptr_intptr(Native Method)
 at libmono.00023913(Native Method)
 at libmono.mono_runtime_invoke(mono_runtime_invoke:136)
 at libunity.002d0710(Native Method)
 at libunity.002d06c0(Native Method)
 at libunity.00431408(Native Method)
 at data@app@com.007604bd(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you reproduce it yourself? [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14023479/3183423) guy has a clue on this error. Try to disable parts of the code that use plugins or do extensive work and keep building re-enabling parts one at a time.

Comment: should I remove the plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following reason to face this issue:

- The error is because of some sort of memory issue
- Segment Violations can occur due to a wide range of problems (usually
  bad pointer or array over/under flows) and is not systemic to any one
  type of software or product.
- If you have programming (or are using) a plugin that in turn uses
  native C/C++ code through the NDK, this may indicate a bug in that
  native code. Otherwise, this is a bug in the firmware of the device
  or emulator you are testing upon.
- If you can reproduce this in an emulator, on a Nexus device with the
  original ROM, or on a variety of devices from different
  manufacturers, it is probably a bug in Android itself. In that case,
  please create a sample project that can reproduce the error, and post
  it along with the entire stack trace to http://b.android.com, the
  Android OS issue tracker.
- If you are only encountering this on one device or one third-party
  ROM, it is probably a more specific bug -- your best bet is to
  contact the device manufacturer or ROM publisher with your symptoms.
- And one more thing i want to acknoledge regarding this issue is that
  the most of samsung device has memory allocation issuees due to some
  sort of customize OS.