# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 32140

Tags: android, fatal-error, crash-reports, android-logcat

50% of the time when running my app I'm getting this error

```
06-20 12:56:51.183: A/libc(32140): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 32140 (example.www)
```

I just have to reopen the app and then it works. But I don't know why I'm getting this error and the app crashes.
I'm working with big images with dimensions, almost 1200x1200px and setting that as a background. I also use that image as a bitmap for some other activities as background. Also doing some calls to a server and getting JSON data back. 
Hope I gave enough information, because I don't know what to look for...
I'm developing for 4.1.2

**Complete Logcat**

```
   06-20 13:02:38.823: W/ActivityThread(4102): Application eu.sexample.www can be debugged on port 8100...
06-20 13:02:38.983: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 114K, 7% free 12283K/13191K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
06-20 13:02:38.988: I/dalvikvm-heap(4102): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.398MB for 5954576-byte allocation
06-20 13:02:39.008: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 5% free 18096K/19015K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 22ms
06-20 13:02:39.053: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 18097K/19015K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
06-20 13:02:39.088: I/dalvikvm-heap(4102): Grow heap (frag case) to 41.112MB for 23818256-byte allocation
06-20 13:02:39.103: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 41357K/42311K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 16ms
06-20 13:02:39.168: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5815K, 16% free 35916K/42695K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
06-20 13:02:39.193: E/Location(4102): 51.1878642, 4.3802626
06-20 13:02:39.283: D/libEGL(4102): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-20 13:02:39.283: D/libEGL(4102): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-20 13:02:39.288: D/libEGL(4102): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-20 13:02:39.288: D/(4102): Device driver API match
06-20 13:02:39.288: D/(4102): Device driver API version: 10
06-20 13:02:39.288: D/(4102): User space API version: 10 
06-20 13:02:39.288: D/(4102): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
06-20 13:02:39.323: D/OpenGLRenderer(4102): Enabling debug mode 0
06-20 13:02:42.413: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 448K, 14% free 37130K/42695K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
06-20 13:02:42.423: I/dalvikvm-heap(4102): Grow heap (frag case) to 42.664MB for 5954576-byte allocation
06-20 13:02:42.433: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 12% free 42941K/48519K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 13ms
06-20 13:02:42.478: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 12% free 42941K/48519K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
06-20 13:02:42.478: I/dalvikvm-heap(4102): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 23818256-byte allocation
06-20 13:02:42.498: D/dalvikvm(4102): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 12% free 42931K/48519K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
06-20 13:02:42.498: E/dalvikvm-heap(4102): Out of memory on a 23818256-byte allocation.
06-20 13:02:42.498: I/dalvikvm(4102): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
06-20 13:02:42.498: I/dalvikvm(4102):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41585508 self=0x415758c8
06-20 13:02:42.498: I/dalvikvm(4102):   | sysTid=4102 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074532144
06-20 13:02:42.498: I/dalvikvm(4102):   | schedstat=( 2709445063 154759556 1906 ) utm=227 stm=43 core=2
06-20 13:02:42.498: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-20 13:02:42.498: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
06-20 13:02:42.498: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3436)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3371)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:426)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:184)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-20 13:02:42.503: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at eu.sexample.www.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 13:02:42.508: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 13:02:42.513: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-20 13:02:42.513: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-20 13:02:42.513: I/dalvikvm(4102):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 13:02:42.513: A/libc(4102): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 4102 (example.www)
```

Comment: have you used multi-threading in your application??

Comment: Can you post here complete LogCat?

Comment: added complete logcat. By multi-threading, you mean asynctask? Then yes I'm using asyncTasks for the network operations

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The real error is `Out of memory on a 23818256-byte allocation`. You are attempting to allocate a ~22MB block of memory, and you do not have that much free memory available, let alone a contiguous block that large.

In this case, this is coming from a drawable resource. ~22MB would be a truly massive image, more like 2400x2400 than 1200x1200.

Your process heap size is 48MB, which is substantial, but ~22MB is almost half your heap budget.

I would recommend that you find out which drawable resource this is (looks like it might be a background of a `RelativeLayout`), then reduce its size and the sizes of similar images. Here, by "size" I mean total pixel count, not the on-disk size, as what matters is the decompressed size in RAM, not how big the image is on disk.

Also, this might be an issue of resource directories. For example, if you put your 1200x1200 image in `res/drawable/`, that effectively is synonymous with `res/drawable-mdpi/`. If this device happens to be an `-xhdpi` device, then that would explain the memory usage, as Android will try to upsample this image and double each of the dimensions.

Comment: I'm using indeed a xhdpi device. I don't think I have an image of 22MB but to be certain I'll check it out. And you are also correct I've putted the image in the res/drawable folder. If what you are saying is correct, then your theory should also be correct: /res/drawable us synonymous with mdpi, then when running on my xhdpi device it will scale it to 2400x2400. I'll try it out and I'll let you know how it went, give me a few minutes

Comment: Ow yeah, I'm trying it out at the moment I'm typing this but another question: I have another image, with almost the same size and dimensions and that one works pretty well, maybe have an idea how that can be? It is also directed in res/drawable

Comment: @mXX: That one got loaded first, presumably. If you do not want the image scaled when it is loaded, but rather when it is rendered (trading RAM for CPU/GPU), try moving the resource to `res/drawable-nodpi/`. I don't use massive image backgrounds like this, but I think that will help. That being said, you're not going to be able to have more than a couple of 1200x1200 drawable resources, even if they are not scaled to 2400x2400 when they are loaded.

Comment: If I don't want it scaled, I basically just put it in the xhdpi folder right? And also provide a drawable for the mdpi and hdpi

Comment: @mXX: That would work too. It will still scale for those densities that you do not support (e.g., `-tvdpi` for the Nexus 7), but usually it will downscale from a higher density image (e.g., `-tvdpi` would downsample the `-hdpi` or `-xhdpi`), which caps how much memory the downscaled image would consume.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was driving me crazy...  I placed my images in `res/drawable/xhdpi` and it all worked fine! Thank you again!

Comment: All the images in my app are .png's and the largest is 540x960.  I have no issues whatsoever on my test phone with 960x540 resolution.  However on Samsung S3 with higher screen resolution I am getting fairly regular `fatal signal 11 (sigsegv) at (code=1)` messages with NO stack trace being reported.  Any suggestions on how I can determine what is causing the problem on the S3?  (BTW, I put that large .png in both the mdpi and the hdpi drawable folders. Does that help or hurt this problem?)

Comment: @CommonsWare can you help with similar issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548166/audiorecord-how-do-i-use-a-common-buffer-to-use-it-for-processing-and-storing

Comment: @CommonsWare what about `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000018` any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In your AndroidMenifest.

`<application.... android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />`

Works for me.

Comment: This worked for me too.  In order to disable hardware acceleration for a webview (which is what I had to do in order to avoid this crash) simply do `webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace FrameLayout with LinearLayout in XML layout