# Java + NDK load native library

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I am trying to load native library. I built the library using the ndk.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("NativeRegister");
}
```

Every time this call end with:

```
09-14 17:21:26.420: E/dalvikvm(871): VM aborting
09-14 17:21:26.420: A/libc(871): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 871 (ookbook.chaper2)
```

Do you know where could be the problem?

Comment: Does the library have JNI_OnLoad?

Comment: Anything in your log between _loadLibrary_ and _aborting_?

Answer (score 0):

usually, it is memory operation problem if the log started with "A/libc". so you have to double check your native c code carefully, like array index, memory size and access, type casting and so on. there are some similar questions on stackoverflow, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211933/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000000-code-1-thread-32140).