# Getting Fatal Signal 11 error

Tags: android, sip

I am making a SIP client using PortSIP library made based on [AndroidSIPSample](http://www.portsip.com/downloads/voip/AndroidSample.zip) project. I get the following error:

```
01-09 02:00:52.730: A/libc(750): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000c0d (code=1), thread 750 (ovative.innovox)
```

The error is not coming when I am running [AndroidSIPSample](http://www.portsip.com/downloads/voip/AndroidSample.zip) project downloaded from PortSIP website.

Following is my logcat output:

```
01-09 02:00:47.910: D/dalvikvm(750): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/in.innovative.innovox-2/libportsipcore.so 0x416fc190
01-09 02:00:47.981: D/dalvikvm(750): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/in.innovative.innovox-2/libportsipcore.so 0x416fc190
01-09 02:00:48.400: D/dalvikvm(750): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 63K, 8% free 2656K/2876K, paused 81ms, total 91ms
01-09 02:00:48.432: I/dalvikvm-heap(750): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.087MB for 2457616-byte allocation
01-09 02:00:48.510: D/dalvikvm(750): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 5053K/5280K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
01-09 02:00:49.530: D/dalvikvm(750): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 4% free 5351K/5540K, paused 53ms, total 57ms
01-09 02:00:49.550: I/dalvikvm-heap(750): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.451MB for 1127536-byte allocation
01-09 02:00:49.630: D/dalvikvm(750): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 6450K/6644K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
01-09 02:00:51.990: I/Choreographer(750): Skipped 167 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-09 02:00:52.010: D/gralloc_goldfish(750): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-09 02:00:52.730: A/libc(750): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000c0d (code=1), thread 750 (ovative.innovox)
```

I don't know what is causing it, I even put images in xhdpi drawable folder for xhdpi devices according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211933/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000000-code-1-thread-32140). But still getting the error.

Please help me solve this error.

Comment: This issue is because of the image size and when you run the code on device and if the device does not have enough memory then it shows out of memory error

Comment: @jyomin But I am not getting error when I added same images in AndroidSIPSample project & ran it.

Comment: I am getting error even after removing images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error because I was passing wrong argument to a method of the PortSIP library, so because of that the library was throwing error.