# Trying to make button go to another screen- app closes

Tags: android

I'm trying to make it so when the user presses a button on main activity screen, it will take them to another activity screen (called create). but when I run my app and click the button, the app just goes black then goes to my phone home screen.

Here's my Main activity code:

```
 package com.app.supermarketaislefinder;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreate);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, create.class));
            }
        });

        }

        }
```

This is the XML Code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/paper">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSettings"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="344dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settingsbutton_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bree_serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/viewbutton_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bree_serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View your Shopping LIst"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonSettings"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonCreate" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorMain"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bree_serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Supermarket Aisle Finder"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreate"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bree_serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Create your Shopping List"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the manifest code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.supermarketaislefinder">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".create" />
        <activity android:name=".view" />
        <activity android:name=".settings"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You may getting any exception on create activity. look into logs and share code of this class.

Comment: share your logs details, nothing wrong in your code

Comment: Is your other activity registered in the manifest?

Comment: This is what it said in logcat:

Comment: 06-06 17:06:44.622 7885-7885/com.app.supermarketaislefinder A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7885 (rketaislefinder)

Comment: @Bob like this, do you mean?         <activity android:name=".create" />

Comment: you haven't declared your button that is why..

Comment: oh...where do I do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Post your manifest file. You might be missing something (as pointed out by @Bob)

Comment: Updated with manifest code

Comment: Second button in your layout doesn't have an id.

Comment: i'm not using that button at the moment- would that still matter @Rabee

Comment: It shouldn't...

Comment: Use this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211933/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000000-code-1-thread-32140?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211933/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000000-code-1-thread-32140?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: According to the link above. The problem is in the size of the background drawables in your layout. So, by removing the background drawables as in the answer below, your code worked flawlessly.

Comment: Ohh you mean the background of the buttons? But what if I wanted to have a background for the buttons e.g with border and colour

Comment: Check the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and change the name of button or class as per your project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button buttonCreate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonCreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreate);

    buttonCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Create.class));
        }
    });

}
}
```

Replace your XML code with this in this code I am not getting any error .

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSettings"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="344dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="View your Shopping LIst"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonSettings"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonCreate" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="384dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Supermarket Aisle Finder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="36sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCreate"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Create your Shopping List"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />
```

Comment: Hi. I tried that, but still got this error '06-06 17:16:15.864 9316-9316/com.app.supermarketaislefinder A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 9316 (rketaislefinder)
'

Comment: Yes thank you. But I'm trying to add the colours to the buttons again

Answer (score -1):

Is the activity declared in your manifest file?

Comment: </activity>
        <activity android:name=".create" /> If that's what you mean